# Directory Configuration in C#

Tags: c#, path, directory, appdata

I would like to read from a htm file, that is located to the following directory:

```
C:\Users\**NAME**\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

How can I change the path, so that I can use it from another computer, where the **user name is not equal** to the one above?

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData + @"Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Environment.SpecialFolder` is an enumeration, you need to call `GetFolderPath` to get the actual path.  Also ApplicationData includes the "Roaming" part, so you don't need that

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Signatures"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData,Environment.SpecialFolderOption.None) + @"\Microsoft\Signatures"
```

Check also the possibility of parameter **Environment.SpecialFolderOption**